# Checkboxes on a Materialize table implemented in Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, checkbox, materialize

My question is in 2 parts.

I would like to add a checkbox to a table. What's the best way to do that?

Secondly, I would like to have all checkboxes selected when the top most checkbox is selected, and to have all the checkboxes de-selected when the top most checkbox is clicked again. However, the user should also be able to select a few items on the checkbox; if they choose to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a materialize checkbox, I would recommend at their documentation.  You will probably need to use a little jQuery to initialize and interact with the elements.  There is something at the end of the linked page like this:

```
Template.yourTemplate.onRendered(function() {
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('input#input_text, textarea#textarea1').characterCounter();
   });
});
```

Regarding meteor specifically, I would check out something like [autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform).  You can define the options in the schema with this [package](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) (same author as autoform), and will be able to do things such as multi-select and parent/child nesting.